# Vertical axis on Excel plot extends beyond where it's supposed to?

Tags: excel, plot, office365

I ran into this interesting "feature" while plotting something in Excel (Office 365 ProPlus, Version 1705, Build 8201.2200).  The plot is shown below, with the other axes removed.

[image]

The vertical axis is supposed to extend from `0.0` to `1.0E-12`, and it does -- as far as the vertical is concerned. There is an additional value of `1.2E-13` that seems to be floating out there for no reason. The same thing happens if I set the vertical axis Bounds to "Auto".

Interestingly, if I delete the orange curve (whose maximum value is well within the current vertical axis), the vertical axis values seem to correctly snap to their proper positions:

[image]

What is going on, and how can I fix this error? Is it a bug, or do I have a box checked that I shouldn't have checked?